# How to write inside a DIV box with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a mini-game where a player attacks a npc and in the center is a white box (div) that I call (log), because when the player damages/attacks the npc, I want to be able for that open white space to log what happened.

I'm using the getElementById(log) and then adding something along the lines of "document.write("You attacked X npc"), but its not working.

Any idea on how I can get text INSIDE the box and not outside it? Thanks

Comment: ^ what he said.  or just post your code.

Comment: Give div id `log` and use any one of the methods i listed

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += '<br>Some new content!';
```

```html
<div id="log">initial content</div>
```

Answer (score 43):

You can use one of the following methods:

```
document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = "text";

document.getElementById('log').innerText = "text";

document.getElementById('log').textContent = "text";
```

For Jquery:

```
$("#log").text("text");

$("#log").html("text");
```

Comment: Do these all do the same thing? Are there more was to do the same thing? How do they differ from each other?

Comment: innerHTML sets string as html, innerText set text as escaped string so it doesn't get interpreted as html , textContent edits text node directly.

Comment: Does it mean that textContent escapes as well like innerText?

Answer (score 16):

HTML:

```
<div id="log"></div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("log").innerHTML="WHATEVER YOU WANT...";
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest Jquery:

```
$("#log").html("Type what you want to be shown to the user");
```

Comment: Why jQuery for something so simple?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **jQuery** and you want to add content to the existing contents of the div, you can use `.html()` within the brackets:

```js
$("#log").html($('#log').html() + " <br>New content!");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="log">Initial Content</div>
```